# JS - conditional property selection

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays with the following structure:

First dictionary:

```
 [{id: 111, abbr: "FBI", name: "Federal Burreau of Investigation"},
 {id: 59, abbr: "CIA", name: "Central Intelligence Agency"},
 {id: 130, abbr: "EU", name: "European Union"}]
```

Second dictionary:

```
 [{id: 28, name: "Administration"},
 {id: 107, name: "Advocacy"},
 {id: 100, name: "Agriculture"},
 {id: 77, name: "Air & Aviation"}]
```

I am trying to create a delimiter function that accesses these objects in the following way:

```
 finalDictionary.push({ delimiter: dictionary[0].abbr.charAt(0) });
```

and correspondingly:

```
 finalDictionary.push({ delimiter: dictionary[i].name.charAt(0) });
```

My aim is to make the method universal and diminish the amount of final code. As you see, the only difference here is the property by which I am accessing the dictionary, 'abbr' and 'name'. I tried to do it the following way:

```
 var ext = (name === 'agencies') ? 'abbr' : 'name';
 finalDictionary.push({ delimiter: dictionary[i].ext.charAt(0) });
```

However, I get an error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
```

The question is how can I conditionally access the object property? Maybe, there is a better approach than this one? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is my first question on SO, pardon me in case I failed to comply with the regulations.

Comment: What is `i`, and which dictionary is `dictionary`? Can you post a [MCVE], ideally in a live snippet in your question?

Comment: Pls also tell what's the desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, next time I will. SO looks like a pretty sophisticated resource in terms of politics :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
dictionary[i].ext.charAt(0)
```

`dictionary[i].ext` assume that you have a property `ext` inside `dictionary[i]` which you don't and therefore it returns undefined.

than what happens is `undefined.charAt(0)` which raises your error

Change it to:

```
dictionary[i][ext].charAt(0)
```

Than the property here is the value of `ext` which is `'abbr'` or `'name'`

Comment: Thank you, this is it! I should have used bracket notation to access the property via string which I get as a result of my ternary. Appreciated :)

Comment: This is a matter of 2 more minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no property named `ext` in the example json you have shown, that is why you are facing this error.

Comment: Ext is a variable storing the name of the property to be used, I am getting it via a ternary